# How do i make the image look like its directly outside my window

Tags: rendering, node-editor, shaders

[image][image: here[![and here]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC3ye.jpg)
So basically im trying to put a picture outside my window (in eevee) and when i do it appears far away and blurred, is there any way to put it directly outside my window? The roof also turns green whenever i change the overall colour of the background, say if i changed it to a blue sky the roof would turn blue as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to achieve this, one would be to enable images as planes addon.
It is already included in blender so just go to prefernecs and enable it.

Once its enabled press `SHIFT + A > Image > Images as planes` and select the image you want to import.
Now simply place the new plane where your window is and transform it as per your needs